# Lazyloading not working with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, lazy-loading, fluent

As I'm just starting with Fluent NHibernate, I'm creating a very simple example of application, witch classes are described below:

//////////////////////////////DOMAIN CLASSES///////////////////////////////

```
public class Company
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public Company()
    {
        Employees = new List<Employee>();
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int Idade { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual Company objCompany { get; set; }
}
```

//////////////////////////////MAPPING CLASSES///////////////////////////////

```
public class CompanyMap : ClassMap<Company>
{
    public CompanyMap()
    {
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasMany(x => x.Employees).Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Idade);
        Map(x => x.FirstName);
        Map(x => x.LastName);
        Map(x => x.Cargo);
        References(x => x.objCompany);
    }
}
```

//////////////////////////////MY QUESTION///////////////////////////////

So what I'd like to do is to load an instance of COMPANY without loadind the list of EMPLOYEES and then load only if necessary.

I guess that it's referenced to the concept of lazyloadind and as I have already declared the class level LazyLoad(); I'm not understanding why NHibernate still loading everything when I load a COMPANY object.

Here is a exemple of code to search for a company object:

PS.: _nhibernateSession is already a openned session.

```
public static IList<Company> FindAll()
{
    return _nhibernateSession.QueryOver<Company>().List();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% sure it doesn't fire another query to load the list of employees? Use sql server profiler to figure it out...

Anyways, the proper way to map it is

```
HasMany(x => x.Employees).Cascade.All().LazyLoad();
```

Comment: Yes I know it's firing another query to load and I've tried to map this way too, but it still loading the list of Employees.

Comment: In my official project, I have some tables with many OneToMany relationships and if i load every list, everytime a search for the parent object, my applicatiom may have some perfomance problems.

Comment: In a code example...

If I search for all companys:

    IList<Company> mylist = CompanyRepository.FindAll();

at this point.. I'd like to have ONLY the object Company WITHOUT ANY list (null).

And THEN, IF I need... I get the list of employees just accessing the employees list. Like this:

    foreach (var item in mylist[0].employees)
    {
        var test = item.Name;
    }

If I'm wrong, please let me know. 

Thanks for trying to help-me !